# CCSM: How to add mouse-binding for moving a window within wall

Tags: shortcut-keys, compiz, mouse, shortcuts, ccsm

I want to be able to use my **special mouse buttons** to **move windows between workspaces**:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Button 7</kbd>   should move the active window one workspace to the right.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Button 6</kbd>   should move the active window one workspace to the left.

This worked fine in Ubuntu 14.04 and earlier versions: CCSM > Desktop Wall > Bindings > Move with window within wall > [Set appropriate combination]

In 14.10, I can only set keyboard shortcuts! How can I set up my desired combination next to the default keyboard shortcuts? Is there a compiz config file that I could manually edit?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should be fully configurable in the  compiz-settings-manager.  You can install it with a search in 'apps'.

Comment: That's not true. These settings aren't in CCSM. Please read what I wrote:
CCSM > Desktop Wall > Bindings > 'Move with window within wall'
There, you will find no such setting.